# Error on installing tidyverse on linux Debian

Tags: r, tidyverse

The error on installing tidyverse when setting up linux on R, i have tried the commands below and still nothing has worked.

```
Using PKG_LIBS=-lfreetype -lpng16 -ltiff -lz -ljpeg -lbz2
-----------------------------[ ANTICONF ]-------------------------------
Configuration failed to find one of freetype2 libpng libtiff-4 libjpeg. Try installing:
 * deb: libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: freetype-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libfreetype_dev libpng16_dev libtiff_dev libjpeg_dev (Solaris)
If freetype2 libpng libtiff-4 libjpeg is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a freetype2 libpng libtiff-4 libjpeg.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/home/__fr34k/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/ragg’
ERROR: dependency ‘ragg’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/__fr34k/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/tidyverse’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpVJh5Ze/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidyverse") :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

I get an error above when i try to reinstall even after trying the commands below.

`sudo apt install  libssl-dev libxml2-dev libfontconfig1-dev libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev`

Comment: what happens when you run `sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev`?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to build from source? Binaries for Debian - https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/ , https://packages.debian.org/sid/r-cran-tidyverse ,

Comment: I fixed the error by install the r-cran-components